# CSS responsive equal height columns with buttons under each div that wrap properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

[image: Multi column with buttons]

Hello! I know this has been a common/recurring thing for developers. Something that should be so easy but never is. :( I've looked around and found some solutions but nothing that's working for my particular needs. If you look at the attached image, you will see what I'm trying to accomplish. In full width mode (desktop perhaps), two divs in each column with a button under each div (of course the buttons will be styled divs but for the sake of clarity, I'll call them buttons). The two divs above the buttons must be equal height even though they don't contain equal content. When viewed on mobile, the div/button pairs should wrap as shown in bottom part of the image - so that the proper button stays with its div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a JavaScript approach, something like this would work:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zMhsC/4/)

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Some content.</div>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        This div has more content. This div has more content. This div has more content.
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

```
div.outer {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div.outer, button { width: 80px; }

div.inner { background-color: yellow; }

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  div.outer {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

```
var inners = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
var maxHeight = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < inners.length; i++) {
    if (inners[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight)
        maxHeight = inners[i].offsetHeight;
}
for (var i = 0; i < inners.length; i++)
    inners[i].style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Minimal JS, quite efficient. I've implemented it on my project and it's working well. Thank you, Josh!

Answer (score 2):

I gave this a lot of thought and the only way you can accomplish this in a "real world" scenario is either with JS (Josh Bjelovuk has given you a good answer on that already) or with duplicate content and display tables. I say "real world" because there are some experimental content swapping CSS properties but they have VERY limited support.

```
<div class="container">
    <div><p>This one has a little content</p></div>
    <a class="show-small" href="Javascript;">Click Here!</a>
    <div><p>What is the difference between ignorance and apathy? I don’t know, and I don’t care.</p></div>
    <a class="show-small" href="Javascript;">Click Here!</a>
</div>
<div class="container hide-small">
    <a href="Javascript;">Click Here!</a>
    <a href="Javascript;">Click Here!</a>
</div>
```

```
body { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 40px;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 10px 3px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
}
div p {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #2CB32C;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.show-small { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 30em) {
    .container { display: block; }
    div > div {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    a { border-radius: 0; }
    .show-small { display: block; }
    .hide-small { display: none; }
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/g6TeY/1/)

Comment: Thanks Ian. I used Josh's method because a) it works very nicely and b) Stack Overflow was down for maintenance this morning and I couldn't add comments! However, I like your method as well so I've saved the code locally in the event this comes up again. Thanks very much!

Comment: Surely that doesn't actually do what the OP asked: if I make the display view narrower in your fiddle, so that the buttons wrap, they no longer have the same height. 7 years later and I still haven't found a way, other than javascript, to ensure that heights are equal!